# Posting object/keyvalue with file upload to asp.net core api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, xamarin.forms, asp.net-core-webapi

I have been trying to post a file with additonal information to asp.net core 3+ post api. If I send these params individually, it works. However, I want to send the required information at once.

**My Model in ASP.Net Core 3.1**

```
public class PostItem
{
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}
```

**The Post API**

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post(PostItem item)
        {
            try
            {
                if (item == null)
                    return BadRequest();
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
                //Do Something here
                return Ok();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, ex.Message + "Internal server error");
            }
        }
```

**Calling the API from Xamarin client**

```
MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
var values = new[]
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Title", postItem.Title)
};
foreach(var keyValue in values)
{
      content.Add(new StringContent(keyValue.Value), keyValue.Key);
}

foreach (string file in imagePaths)
{
    byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
    content.Add(new ByteArrayContent(byteArray), "file", Path.GetFileName(file));
}
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.PostAsync(Path.Combine(ApplicationConstants.apiUrl, "item/"), content);
//read response result as a string async into json var
var responsestr = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

***I am getting 415 error Unsupported Media Type***

> The question is how to send the required parameter from Xamarin Client
>   or how to include FileUpload as part of an object and send it to the
>   api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decorate the input parameter in your post method with a `[FromForm]` tag to bind to the form.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromForm] PostItem item)
{

}
```

This is assuming that your PostItem class matches the form you are posting. Adding `[FromForm]` should at least fix the 415.

Comment: You are awsome.